# Vue.js - DOM not updating after data change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on a Vue.js project, and I am having trouble with the DOM not updating after a data change. Here's the relevant part of my code:

Template:

```
<div>
  <h1 ref="title">{{ customerName }}</h1>
  <!-- Other template elements -->
</div>
```

Script:

```
async updateCustomerInformation(selectedGroup) {
  if (this.newCustomerName) {
    try {
      await axios.put(`api/groups/${selectedGroup.id}`, {
        data: { customerName: this.newCustomerName },
      }).then(result => {
        this.customerName = result.data.data.attributes.customerName;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.errorMessage = 'An error occurred while updating the group. Please refresh the page and try again.';
      this.snackbar = true;
    }
  }
},
```

I can see that the customerName is being updated correctly in the data, but the DOM element bound to customerName does not update. I have already tried using a watch but it seems to have no effect.

```
watch: {
  customerName() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.title.$forceUpdate();
    });
  }
},
```

Any suggestions on how to force the DOM to update after the data change would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because this.customerName inside the Axios function so (this) refers to axios itself, try to define it in the code as a different constant like this:

```
async updateCustomerInformation(selectedGroup) {
    // define it here
    const me = this;
    if (this.newCustomerName) {
    try {
        await axios.put(`api/groups/${selectedGroup.id}`, {
            data: { customerName: this.newCustomerName },
        }).then(result => {
            // use it like this
            me.customerName = result.data.data.attributes.customerName;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        this.errorMessage = 'An error occurred while updating the group. Please refresh the page and try again.';
        this.snackbar = true;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it didn't work. I believe that the solution you provided is unnecessary in this case. The arrow function in the then block already maintains the correct context of 'this', so there's no need to use an additional 'me' variable to store the reference to 'this'.

Comment: oh I didn't realize it, well can you share the data or the vue instance ? or  data: {
    customerName: 'John'
  },